# How to create a form on the client side to allow them to submit products

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, submit, product

I have to create a form on a page of the website that allows user to submit new products.

I'm using WooCommerce.

There is a way to do this ?

Like that : https://toolset.com/learn/create-an-ecommerce-wordpress-site/how-to-create-a-front-end-form-for-adding-woocommerce-products/

But the plugin is paid... :(

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You could give them permission to only add products: https://toolset.com/documentation/user-guides/custom-woocommerce-roles-admin-capabilities/

Comment: Hello,I want a form on a public page.